# Is it acceptable to throw exceptions when not getting expected JSON data?

Tags: java, android, json, exception

Working on an android app which gathers data from the Open Weather API as a JSON. However the JSON does not always contain the same keys (ie. sometimes cloud data or a weather description is included, sometimes it isn't).

Right now my code looks like (with some extra getters/setters I didn't include here):

```
public class WeatherDescrip {

    private String weather;
    private String weather_Desc;
    private String icon;

    public WeatherDescrip(JSONObject weatherObj) {
        try {
            weather = weatherObj.getString("main");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            weather = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            weather_Desc = weatherObj.getString("description");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            weather_Desc = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            icon = weatherObj.getString("icon");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            icon = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Basically if the JSON I get from the API call doesn't have the necessary key I let the program throw an exception, which will usually happen with at least one piece of data each time the app is run (there is more done like this).

If anyone could please let me know whether this is an acceptable way to code, and possibly how to better implement this I would much appreciate it.

If you haven't noticed I'm also a total noob, sorry in advance if this is a terrible way of doing this.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally not the correct forum for asking opinions, as you're asking for subjective opinions, there's technically no way to gauge a 'correct' answer, although you're free to select whatever answer you choose, if any ;-)

But in the nature of good will, I'll give you a few of my opinions.

Firstly, Exceptions are for just that, exceptions. If you have a scenario where you are in control of the code, and are aware of a potential for something not to occur in an 'ideal' way (e.g. like this, you're receiving dodgy data), then code for it, i.e.

```
if (data.contains("somethingOfInterest")) {
    consume(data);
} else {
    getDataFromSomewhereElse();
}
```

Rather than throw an exception, and force your program to handle it somewhere else (or not). [Here's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) some additional information on why it's not a good idea to use exceptions for control flow.

Also, and this is advice from personal experience; in most scenarios, it's a good idea to do as little as makes sense within an Object's constructor, as it's more ugly to recover if exceptions do occur inside a constructor's method body. Instead, it may be better to encapsulate the logic you have there in some other factory-esque class or method, passing only the gathered data to the constructor. Something like:

```
public class WeatherDescrip {
    private String weather;
    private String weather_Desc;
    private String icon;

    public WeatherDescrip(String weather, String weather_Desc, String icon) {
        this.weather = weather;
        this.weather_Desc = weather_Desc;
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}

...

public static WeatherDescrip createWeatherDescrip(JSONObject weatherObj) {
    if (!weatherObj.containsKey("main") 
        || !weatherObj.containsKey("description")
        || !weatherObj.containsKey("icon")) {
        throw SomeNewMeaningfulException("That I understand and can explicitly handle");
        or....
        return getMyDataFromSomeWhereElse();
    }

    return new WeatherDescrip(
        weatherObj.getString("main"),
        weatherObj.getString("description"),
        weatherObj.getString("icon")
    );
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's acceptable to throw exceptions whenever you decide. You just need to play how you want to handle it.

Is it acceptable to crash the program and boot your user back to the home screen? *Absolutely not. Ever*

Just read your data and handle the exceptions gracefully - no icon? Display a default. No data? Tell the user there is a problem right now so they aren't misled by the old data being displayed.

An alternate to avoid the majority of exceptions is to use [GSON and Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-getting-started-with-java-json-serialization-deserialization) (I've linked a useful set of tutorials, not the home of GSON or Retrofit). With GSON you can create a model object, automatically map the data and then on your getters *always* return a value even if the JSON was incomplete

Example:

```
class MyObj {

    @SerializedName("main")
    private String weather;

    public String getWeather() {
        String weatherResult = weather;
        if (weatherResult == null || "".equals(weatherResult) {
            weatherResult = getString(R.strings.weather_unavailable);
        }
        return weatherResult;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception is usually reserved for when an error occurs, rather than having it it being an expected result of running your code, since there is overhead in throwing an exception which can make your program execute (slightly) slower.

Realistically, it can be used whenever you like, however you like, but I might instead suggest using [`has()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)) to check if the key exists before trying to access it. It's a more efficient way of achieving the same result, without having to throw or catch an exception.

```
if(weatherObj.has('description')) {
    weather_Desc = weatherObj.getString("description");
} else {
    weather_Desc = null;
}
```